# How do I stop sequelize from creating an unwanted primary key when inserting data?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model without any primary key:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const usersDoors = sequelize.define('usersDoors',
    {
      user_uid: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      door_uid: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      property_manager_uid: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      tenant_uid: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: 'users_doors',
      indexes: [
        {
          name: 'doors_users_indexes',
          unique: true,
          fields: ['user_uid', 'door_uid', 'property_manager_uid', 'tenant_uid'],
        },
      ],
      classMethods: {
        associate: (models) => {
          usersDoors.belongsTo(models.users, { foreignKey: 'user_uid' });
          usersDoors.belongsTo(models.doors, { foreignKey: 'door_uid' });
          usersDoors.belongsTo(models.propertyManagers, { foreignKey: 'property_manager_uid' });
          usersDoors.belongsTo(models.tenants, { foreignKey: 'tenant_uid' });
        },
      },
    });

  return usersDoors;
};
```

When I insert data (via sequelize), sequelize adds a composite primary key to the table which includes the first 2 columns (user_uid and door_uid). This is breaking my stuff and I don't want it.

How can I stop sequelize from creating an unwanted primary key when inserting data?

More details:

- dialect: postgresql
- sequelize (the node package) version: 3.30.2
- postgresql version: psql (9.6.1, server 9.5.5)
- node version (this has nothing to do with anything): 6.9.1

And finally, here is the sequelize migration for this model:

```
const tableName = 'users_doors';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable(tableName, {
      user_uid: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'uid',
        },
      },
      door_uid: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'doors',
          key: 'uid',
        },
      },
      property_manager_uid: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: 'property_managers',
          key: 'uid',
        },
      },
      tenant_uid: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: 'tenants',
          key: 'uid',
        },
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    })
      .then(() => {
        return queryInterface.addIndex('users_doors',
          ['user_uid', 'door_uid', 'property_manager_uid', 'tenant_uid'],
          {
            indexName: 'doors_users_indexes',
            indicesType: 'UNIQUE',
          });
      });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable(tableName)
      .then(() => {
        return queryInterface.removeIndex('users_doors', ['user_uid', 'door_uid', 'property_manager_uid', 'tenant_uid']);
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add attribute to sequelize model, as well as to the migrations, that would be your primary key

```
// in sequelize model definition
const usersDoors = sequelize.define('usersDoors',
{
  id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
  },
  user_uid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
  },
  // other fields

// in the migrations file
return queryInterface.createTable(tableName, {
  id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
  },
  user_uid: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'uid',
      },
  },
  // other fields
```

According to the documentation, when you create M:M relation, sequelize automatically creates a primary key which is composed of two foreign keys referencing to tables creating the relation (`users` and `doors` in your case)

> The table will be uniquely identified by the combination of the keys of the two tables

**EDIT**

Assuming that you have used the `belongsToMany` on both `users` and `doors` model there is a way to avoid automatic creation of the `unique index` on `user_uid` and `door_uid`. You need to specify `unique: false` condition in the `through` object of the m:m relation initialisation (in both models to avoid any automatic unique constraints)

```
// in users model
users.belongsToMany(
    models.doors,
    {
        through: { model: models.usersDoors, unique: false },
        foreignKey: 'user_uid'
    }
);

// in doors model
doors.belongsToMany(
    models.users,
    {
        through: { model: models.usersDoors, unique: false },
        foreignKey: 'door_uid'
    }
);
```

Comment: This kind of works as in sequelize doesn't create an additional primary key, but now it is inventing a unique constraint on those same 2 columns where as you'll notice the unique constraint I'm actually setting up is on the 4 columns...

Comment: I have updated the answer concerning the automatic `unique` constraint.

Comment: I ended up just removing the belongsToMany associations and replacing them with multiple hasMany and belongTo associations. This fixed the problem and now the only minor problem left is that sequelize is creating an `id` column as a primary key, which I've never asked for. This I can live with, however since I can simply ignore that column. Would your solution also prevent this less troublesome problem from occurring?

Comment: How about `usersDoors.removeAttribute('id')`? According to the documentation: "And if your model has no primary key at all you can use Model.removeAttribute('id');"

Comment: Adding `unique:false` is the solution. It works also for the case of  `model.belongsTo`. I was having this issue when I used the `include` option. I hope this will help someone